# error 1083 the executable program that this service is configured to run does not implemented the service

Tags: windows-services

getting error while try to start service

Answer (score 41, accepted):

answer: if you are getting this error check the service name and service process installer service name. Both must be the same.

happy coding

Source: http://cut.lu/cddc2c

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, but I need to correct you on something: the service name (as declared inside your service Component) and the service installer name (instance of ServiceInstaller class) must be the same. ServiceProcessInstaller doesn't have a ServiceName nor a Name property.

Comment: yes, its resolved my problem by adding the reference of service in Program.cs class inside function ServicesToRun like  new ServiceName() thanks

Answer (score 23):

Also ensure that in the entry point for the exe (usually the Main procedure) an instance of the your service class (that derives from Service base is created).eg.

```
private static void Main()
        {
            var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                                              {
                                                  new MyService1(),
                                                  new MyService2()
                                              };
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
        }
```

If you do not do this, say you do not include code to create instance of MySerivce2, as above, you will get the error message above when you try to start MyService2.

Comment: yes, its resolved my problem by adding service reference inside ServiceBase. i was missing service reference thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've got same problem. My solution for this was to check the service name and service installer service name. Both must be the same.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.ServiceName = "EmailService";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add another possibility, [see answer #7 on this link](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/error-1083-executable-service-191067.aspx).

The jist of the solution is to assign the service name as you expect it to be at initialization time. In my situation, the Service.`ServiceName` field was not set

Consider using log statements to write the service name just prior to `ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun)`.