# Error while trying to run multiple instances of a windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services

I am trying to run multiple instances of a service on the same server to support several environments.

I tried to modify ServiceInstaller.ServiceName as recommended [here](https://journalofasoftwaredev.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/multiple-instances-of-same-windows-service/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835422/how-do-i-configure-the-name-of-a-windows-service-upon-installation-or-easily-at/836748#836748).

However, [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.servicename(v=vs.110).aspx) "It is crucial that the ServiceName be identical to the ServiceBase.ServiceName of the [Service] class."

Ignoring MSDN, I tried to do it anyway after seeing the two pages that I linked above. However, when I do I get an error saying, "Windows could not start the {Display Name} service on Local Computer. Error 1083: The executable program that this service is configured to run in does not implement the service."

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371099/error-1083-the-executable-program-that-this-service-is-configured-to-run-does-no) confirms that this is the explanation for that error.

Answer (score 0):

This plagued me for a long Time. Then, when I was reading [this Q&A](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28400ffa-f905-4b6b-97f7-2df1166849f9/error-1083-the-executable-program-that-this-service-is-configured-to-run-in-does-not-implement-the?forum=vcgeneral) for the 5th time something hit me.

That article isn't using dynamic names, but I noticed that it is setting ServiceBase.ServiceName in the Main function. It occurred to me that maybe I could do the same dynamically, and it worked.

My main function now looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1(), 
            new Service2(),
            new Service3()
        };

        foreach (serviceBase Service in ServicesToRun)
        {
            service.ServiceName = FunctionToComputeDynamicName(service);
        }
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

I am getting the name from Installer.Context at install time and from App.config at runtime. If you wanted you could also easily get the runtime name using Args[] version of Main.